# web.config custom section inheritance

Tags: web-config, configurationsection, configsection

I'm trying to get a custom web.config section to get inherited by an application's web.config in a website subfolder.

The custom section works fine in the main website, but it appears the custom section isn't inherited.

Other elements in the web.config are getting inherited - it's just this custom section which isn't.

Is this by design? Is there a way to turn on inheritance for custom sections?

Answer (score 0):

Mysteriously.....it's now working.

I found this blog post:
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/133041.aspx

which suggested they should be inherited downwards.

I rebooted and hey presto the whole thing worked.